# How to go to a folder in shell script and do the operation

Tags: bash, git, shell, ubuntu, sh

I have a directory at server path - **/home/user/repos** where all my project folders are placed. like project-a, project-b, project-c etc.
And this gitpull.sh file where I have placed below code is at path **/home/user/automation/git/gitpull.sh**

Now my requirement is this: I want to automate the git pull of all projects at certain time every day which I will set in CRON. But the issue I am facing is the file which I will put in CRON is not working.

I have created a shell script to pull all git repositories from the current directory, which is working fine. But unable to understand how to do git pull from a specified directory's subdirectories, (which is **/home/user/repos** in my case):

I have written the below code:

```
#!/bin/bash

REPOSITORIES="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

IFS=$'\n'

for REPO in `ls "$REPOSITORIES/"`
do
    if [ -d "$REPOSITORIES/$REPO" ]
    then
        echo "Updating $REPOSITORIES/$REPO at `date`"
        if [ -d "$REPOSITORIES/$REPO/.git" ]
        then
            cd "$REPOSITORIES/$REPO"
            git status
            echo "Fetching"
            git fetch
            echo "Pulling"
            git pull
        else
            echo "Skipping because it doesn't look like it has a .git folder."
        fi
        echo "Done at `date`"
        echo
    fi
done
```

I tried writing

```
REPOSITORIES="$( cd "/home/user/repos/")"
```

and

```
REPOSITORIES="$( cd "/home/user/repos/*")"
```

But nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `-C` option of `git`. from `man git`:

> **-C path**
>
> Run as if git was started in `path` instead of the current working
>   directory. When multiple `-C` options are given, each subsequent
>   non-absolute `-C path` is interpreted relative to the preceding `-C path`.
>
> ...

for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

REPOSITORIES="/home/user/repos"

for repo in "$REPOSITORIES"/*/; do
        echo "Updating $repo at `date`"
        if [ -d "$repo/.git" ]; then
                git -C "$repo" status
                echo "Fetching"
                git -C "$repo" fetch
                echo "Pulling"
                git -C "$repo" pull
        else
                echo "Skipping because it doesn't look like it has a .git folder."
        fi
        echo "Done at `date`"
        echo
done
```

the line:

```
for repo in "$REPOSITORIES"/*/; do
```

allows you to [iterate over just directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86722/how-do-i-loop-through-only-directories-in-bash), then if it contains a git repository, run the git commands on that directory.

**edit**: added directory base path

Comment: @Thompson adding an absolute base directory path (`REPOSITORIES` aka your projects folder) allows the script to work even when it's executed by `cron`

Comment: Amazing answer. Thank you so much

Comment: Could be written as `for p in "$REPOSITORIES/"*'/.git/'; do [ "$p" = "$REPOSITORIES/"'*/.git/' ] && continue; repo="${p%*.git/}"` and get away with testing it has a `.git` directory inside. The continue `[ "$p" = "$REPOSITORIES/"'*/.git/' ] && continue` is needed since POSIX shell has no `nullglob` option.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what isn't working?  Is the script doing anything at all?

Is the script in the repos directory?

```
REPOSITORIES="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```

gets you the directory where actual script is, not the directory where you run it from.

```
REPOSITORIES="$( cd "/home/user/repos/")"
```

won't work because you're just starting a subshell, changing directories, then not actually outputting anything.  If you just want to hardcode the directory name, then do this:

```
REPOSITORIES="/home/user/repos"
```

Also, iterating over the output of `ls` is bad practice, ls output isn't designed to be parsed programmatically.  Use

```
for REPO in "$REPOSITORIES"/*
```

Comment: Hi, I have elaborated my question

Comment: A cron job will not run the script with Bash.